# How do I access my method (Java)?

Tags: java

I have tried my best looking in the debugger and testing, but i cannot wrap my mind around this problem.

**In this method it skips going inside the for loop. But in the roll() method, the arraylist gets values?**

```
public int lol(int a) {
    num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < objectDie.getDices().size(); i++) {
        if (objectDie.getDices().get(i) == a) {
            num += a;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

I will post all my classes to create a better image of the code, the troublemaker is at the bottom of the last class I have linked.

**Main**

```
package dicegame;

public class DiceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game test = new Game();
        test.numberDices(); 
        Player spil = new Human();
        spil.takeTurn(test);
    }
}
```

**Game**

```
package dicegame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    Die DieObjekt = new Die();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void numberDices() {
        System.out.println("How many dices would you like to play with?");
        int numberOfDices = sc.nextInt();
        DieObjekt.setNumber(numberOfDices);
    }

    public void play() {
        DieObjekt.roll();
        DieObjekt.printRoll();
    }
}
```

**Die**

```
package dicegame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {

    ArrayList<Integer> dices = new ArrayList<>();
    Random ran = new Random();
    int number;

    public ArrayList<Integer> getDices() {
        return dices;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
         this.number = number;
    }

    public void roll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            dices.add(ran.nextInt(6) + 1);
        }
    }

    public void printRoll() {
        System.out.println("You got ");
        for (int i = 0; i < dices.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(dices.get(i) + ", ");
        }
    }
 }
```

**Human - the last method in this class is the troublemaker**

```
package dicegame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Human implements Player {

    int one, two, three, four, five, six, num;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Die objectDie = new Die();
    Game object = new Game();

    @Override
    public void takeTurn(Game object) {
        object.play();
        System.out.println("If you want to stop, press enter, if not press" 
+"the number on the die that you would like to save");
            int valg = sc.nextInt();
            switch (valg) {
                 case 1:
                one = lol(1);
                System.out.println("You got " + one + " points in the" 
+"ones");
                break;
            case 2:
                two = lol(2);
                System.out.println("You got " + two + " points in the" 
+"twos");
                break;
            case 3:
                three = lol(3);
                System.out.println("You got " + three + " points in the" 
+"threes");
                break;
            case 4:
                four = lol(4);
                System.out.println("You got " + four + " points in the" 
+"fours");
                break;
            case 5:
                five = lol(5);
                System.out.println("You got " + five + " points in the" 
+"fives");
                break;
            case 6:
                 six = lol(6);
                 System.out.println("You got" + six + " points in the" 
+"sixes");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You have stopped, and that is OK");
                break;
        }
    }

    public int lol(int a) {
        num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < objectDie.getDices().size(); i++) {
            if (objectDie.getDices().get(i) == a) {
                num += a;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never add anything to your dices list. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: You never call the objectDie.roll-Method. So your dices-list stays empty.

Comment: Benjamin, yes i do. It is inside the play method, which gets called in human class.
Bear with me Murat K, you were also new to the language once.
What do you mean it never gets assigned? Do you create a new arraylist each time you call it on objects?

Comment: The call of object.play calls roll() to an DieObject in the Game-class. But this is not the same object as in your Human-class.

Comment: For a moment there I thought you were writing German! ("DieObjekt").  Anyways, `Dice` is already plural, so you don't need to attach an 's' on the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class game, you finished the process to create dice list (set the total number and add the valuue with roll) => array list has values

But you forgot to do it with human class

====================

**EDIT**

Here is some suggestion for you to fix your game

```
    /**
     * Don't try to create dice and game in human class, you can take it from previous game which you were created in the static main
     */
    //Die objectDie = new Die();
    //Game object = new Game();
```

Just do it like this

```
Game object;
```

And then store the game object when you have it from takeTurn method

```
public void takeTurn(Game object) {
        this.object = object;
        object.play();

        .....
    }
```

And then in your lol method, try to loop through all the dice of game which you just have from takeTurn method

```
public int lol(int a) {
    num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < object.getDices().size(); i++) {
        if (object.getDices().get(i) == a) {
            num += a;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Finaly, remember to create getDices method for Game class :)

```
public class Game {

    Die DieObjekt = new Die();

    public List<Integer> getDices() {
        return DieObjekt.getDices();
    }
```

Comment: More strictly speaking he is creating an entirely new instance of `Die` inside the `Human` object. He has to use the `Die` Object from the `Game`. I mean overall the whole code is confusing and need to be re-written.

Comment: Is it correct understood, that the ArrayList is stored on the object and not in the class? I am getting a bit confused. 
If so, how do i get the array from the object dices into the Human class?

Comment: Can i get the dices object to this class somehow?

Comment: I updated my answer and give you some suggestion to finish your game :)

Comment: If i could upvote you more than once, i would. This was excellent, and cleared me of all confusion on the topic. Thank you Hung Vo, excellent job!